# Cannot get HexChat to connect to IRC

Tags: windows-7, irc, freenode

I am trying to get IRC up and running on my Windows 7 machine. I have installed HexChat (2.9.6, 64-bit) as a 'normal' install.

Here are the screen shots showing step 1, step 2, and the screen that shows while it is trying unsuccessfully to connect:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this? Why won't it connect?

Comment: Which HexChat version are you using?

Comment: @and31415 I am using HexChat 2.9.6, for x64, since I have a windows-7 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that a firewall (your, your router's, your ISP's...) is blocking all IRC connections. (The server shown is currently online.)

Try connecting using the alternate (non-standard) ports – 6665, 6666, 8000, 8001, or 8002. The Hexchat syntax is `irc.freenode.net/6665` in the server configuration window, or `/server irc.freenode.net 6665` in command line.

Even better, try a SSL-encrypted connection – the standard port is 6697, and freenode also accepts connections on 7000 & 7070. Syntax is the same but with `+port`; e.g. `irc.freenode.net/+6697` (as in the topmost entry of your current server list) or `/server irc.freenode.net +6697`.

Comment: Tried all those... none work :-/ Does it matter how I set the 'login method'?... Sigh... this is so frustrating.

Comment: How can I check about this firewall issue?

Comment: It is worth to try different ports. I had the same issue and `/server irc.freenode.net +7070` worked for me, while other ports failed.

Comment: I have an old HexChat for XP and it couldn't use Freenode until I specified /6665. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but on Mac.. None of the above worked out.

Comment: I've also tried ports, [6665, 6666, 6667, 7000, 7070, 8000, 8001, 8002], no luck